# Add items to ObservableCollection that was created on a background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

In my application, the ViewModels take some time to initialize so I create them on a background thread on startup in order to keep the main window responsive.

I keep getting an exception when I try to add items to an `ObservableCollection` because I'm adding them from another background thread after some processing is done. It's a `NotSupportedException`, saying `Additional information: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.`

Here are the threads I am using:

- Thread A is the WPF UI thread
- Thread B is a worker thread used to create the viewmodels (and the ObservableCollection)
- Thread C is another worker thread that adds items to the ObservableCollection

I am trying to keep my ViewModels separated from my views, so I don't want to have references to the WPF Dispatcher inside my viewmodels, so I can't (don't want to) use `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

I tried to use `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`, but it seems that only works when it's called from the WPF UI thread.

How can I synchronize access to my ObservableCollection so I can add items to it from a background thread? Is there an easy, elegant way to do so? Preferably without using third-party libraries?

I created a small example to illustrate the problem:

AppViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfObservableTest
{
    public class AppViewModel
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; private set; }

        private object _itemsLock = new object();

        public AppViewModel()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AppViewModel ctor thread id: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Items, _itemsLock);

            _timer = new Timer(500);
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        }

        public void StartTimer()
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TimerElapsed thread id: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            lock (_itemsLock)
            {
                Items.Add("Test");
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfObservableTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private AppViewModel _viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Task initTask = Task.Run(() => { _viewModel = new AppViewModel(); });
            initTask.Wait();

            DataContext = _viewModel;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _viewModel.StartTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfObservableTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="0">Start</Button>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1">

        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Stephen Cleary's [Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn605875.aspx) article can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're using a `System.Timers.Timer`. That will fire on a non-UI thread. Instead, consider using a `DispatcherTimer` which will fire on the UI thread.

If however this is just example code to highlight the problem, then in your real code use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` in order to perform the addition on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, I used the `System.Timers.Timer` just as an example to illustrate the problem. Also, I would prefer not to have references to the UI Dispatcher in my ViewModel because the ViewModel should not be tied to any view. Is there another way to get over this problem?

Comment: I don't see the benefit in avoiding using `Application.Current.Dispatcher` from within your view model. You have to hand off from background threads to the UI thread somewhere, and if you're binding to the view model directly, then it's not possible to do it in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can re write code in timer as

```
            private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("TimerElapsed thread id: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            lock (_itemsLock)
            {    
              System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,(Action)delegate()
                  {
                     Items.Add("Test");       
                  });
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would like to keep my viewmodels separate from my views, so I don't want to use Dispatcher.Invoke. I am looking for a solution that does not pollute my viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

Using System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer will fix you problem. But I recommend to rewrite your code and use Task based async operations for your long running initialization task.
What exactly do you want to solve by using the timer?

Comment: I am using the timer just to illustrate the problem. In my real application, the items are added from a background worker thread. If I use task-based async operations for my long running init task, the view models would still be created on a separate thread and the problem will still be there.

Comment: It will but you can return a List<T> of your objects from the worker method and then add these new items in the ObservableCollection either by using await or by Task UITask= task.ContinueWith(() =>
    {
      // add your items here.
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());